# Redhat stopped CentOS 7 updates, Do we need to upgrade to CentOS 8 Stream version?

Tags: centos, centos7, centos8

We are using 'CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)' for production servers. But it seems that Redhat stopped Centos 7 full updates from November 2020 onwards. We are in confusion do we need to upgrade to CentOS 8 or Centos Stream?, As per Centos / wiki official docs. They were providing full/maintenance support for Centos 8 Stream still 2024. Is this Centos 8 Steam version is stable or can we continue with Centos 7 maintenance version?

Reference URLS :
https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#CentOS_version_7

Comment: If you are happy with security updates till 2024 then stick with Centos 7. If you need full updates, given that Centos is being phased out, I would personally begin migration to Centos Stream

Comment: @RamanSailopal We have monthly audit for all production servers/application. So we want all servers/applications to be up-to-date. I found that you have moved to Stream. My concern is do we get software updates like (apache, php etc) for centos 7 maintenance support also let me know Is stream is a Stable version?

Comment: use AlmaLinux (https://almalinux.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In my career i have seen prod servers even running on Solaris 11 which was released 10 years ago and has no support now.

This usually depends, whether the underlying dependencies required by your application change/requires to be updated frequently or not,

If yes - Go with supported version.( which will also run out of support :D )

If No - Stay where you are. ( Best choice Mostly )